# Icacls, problems with permission in subfolder of Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, file-permissions

The problem I have is very persistent.
I have a self-extracting rar file, say files.rar.
This is being uncompressed in C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\XDS\bin

Now this starts a batch file, install.bat, which is in the bin folder.
A 32 bit version of cmd.exe executes this batch file.
So far so good, this all works well.

But: I have to rename one file in the bin folder and delete another. You may wonder, why put a file in there that needs to be deleted? Well, I have a 32 and 64 bit version of a driver. Depending on the target, either one of these must be renamed to NatUSB.dll, while the other must be deleted.

If I run this batch file (simplified):

```
icacls natusb*.dll /inheritance:r /grant:r everyone:(OI)(CI)F
icacls natusb*.dll /T

rename NatUSB_32_ezusb.dll NatUSB32.dll
del    NatUSB_32_winusb.dll
```

I have the following problems:

- I need administrator rights and that is not acceptable for the
  purpose of my company
- Even then I get "Access is denied" for the
  renaming, possibly since there exists already a NatUSB32.dll.
  However, even as administrator I can not delete this file: "Access is
  denied"
- The del NatUSB_32_winusb.dll also gives "Access is denied"

Then I tried to copy the two files to bin2. Reason for this: if I do "icacls bin /T" the list of files I get permission info on is too long, so I hoped to get this info just for a few files. Unfuntunately, I get "Access is denied" (while trying to copy to bin2), even while file permissions for administrator and system are "Full control".
BTW, just icacls natusb*.dll /T does not give any permissions, this only seems to work for entire folders.

When I am in the XSD (parent) folder and do "icacls bin2 /inheritance:r /grant:r everyone:(OI)(CI)F" 
Next, I do "icacls bin2 /T"

bin2 Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)

I still cant copy the few nat*.dll from bin to bin2.

If I try to set access rights on bin folder (very similar to above), I get "bin: The handle is invalid".

BTW, the permissions on bin are as follows:

```
bin NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(F)
    NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(CI)(IO)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
    CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

and as stated before, with icacls I can't change any of this. BTW, the security tab doesn't show duplicate groups or names.

In short: I have problems with renaming, deleting files (must urgent, to solve current problem) and also with copying files from C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XDS\bin to XDS\bin2.

To solve the problems, I need to use icacls or another build in command in a script to force the access rights. Setting access rights in the security tab of a folder is not acceptable: it needs to be done from script. Also: we can not install 3rd party software, certainly not if it is large or has a commercial license. A few kB, perhaps 1MB is for a free to use tool may be acceptable if all else fails.

The solution should also not require administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

This is your main problem:

```
icacls natusb*.dll /inheritance:r /grant:r everyone:(OI)(CI)F
```

The `(OI)(CI)` flags are only valid for directories, not for files.  Because the flags are invalid, the permission is ignored.  So the net effect of this command is to remove all permissions from the file, implicitly denying access to everyone, including administrators.

If you take out the invalid flags, the command will work as expected:

```
icacls natusb*.dll /inheritance:r /grant:r everyone:F
```

However, given your description of the problem, it looks as if you *will* require admin access, because the permissions on the existing folder are read-only for non-administrators.  There's no way around that, unless you can install into a different folder (e.g., in the user's Application Data folder) or change the destination folder permissions in advance.

Note that changing the folder permissions is likely to introduce a security vulnerability.

Comment: Hi; think you very much for your reply. I will try your solution.

Comment: How can I change permissions in advance? Can I save file permissions in a rar file and disable inheritance? So that our subdirectory below PFx86 will allow full access to everyone or owner? Anyway, that is what I will try to find out. You dont need to do all my work, but all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Many problems with copying from xds\bin to xds\bin2, deleting files in xds\bin etc were solved after doing icacls . /reset /T in the bin folder

Comment: You will probably need admin privilege to unpack the rar file into the Program Files folder.  By design, non-administrators do not have access to write into Program Files.

Comment: True, we need admin rights to unpack. The problem has already been solved satisfactory: we make two different rar files, a 32 bits and a 64 bits with the right version of the driver in there renamed to NatUSB.dll. thanks for all help